# Quasi-persönliche Anrede in Vorträgen ("einige von ihnen")

Tags: pronoun, grammatical-number, salutation, declension, grammatical-person

Beim hören vieler Vorträge auf deutsch ist mir aufgefallen, dass der Redner solche Sprachkonstrukte verwendet als ob er nicht viele Personen anspricht, sondern eine.

Zum Beispiel, "wie Sie gerade sehen" (nicht "wie ihr gerade seht"), "ich zeige Ihnen" (nicht "euch"). Deswegen habe ich mir gedacht, es ist wirklich eine persönliche Anrede. So zu sagen, deutsche Kultur der Vorträge.

Heute habe ich aber gehört "einige von ihnen". Das ist aber das Dativ von der dritten grammatischen Person, Plural, nicht von der zweiten! Verstehe ich nicht!

Answer (score 5):

Man braucht bei der Höflichkeitsform der Anrede nicht zu unterscheiden, sie ist immer im Plural, siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sie). *Sie* ist sowohl für einen als auch für viele Adressaten richtig.

Der Dativ in *einige von Ihnen* ist durch die Präposition *von* bedingt; das *einige* kann Akkusativ sein.

Comment: Ach so! Ich wusste es wirklich nicht. In meiner Sprache ist die Höflichkeitsform "Sie" immer Singular. Daher das Missverständnis.

Comment: _Einige von Ihnen_ ist durchaus 2. Person Plural - vielleicht könnte die Antwort das noch klarer artikulieren.

Comment: "von Ihnen" ist definitiv Höflichkeitsform ("Sie", grammatisch 3. Pers. Pl.), 2. Pers. Pl. wäre "einige von euch". Dass "von Ihnen" sich in dem Fall auf mehrere Personen bezieht erkennt man nur an dem "einige".